# Get Input, Add to Page, and Store in localStorage with Pure JS

Tags: javascript, json

I'm stuck trying to get some code working.  The task at hand is:

First, create a form to get user data, like so:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <label id="namefield">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstlast" id="username">
        </br>
        <label id="address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="useraddress">
        </br>
        <label id="emailfield">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="useremail">
        </br>
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Save</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Second, write Javascript that:

1. Creates a JSON object containing an array.
2. Creates a data object to store the user input.
3. Creates an onclick function to:

   1. Get values from each form field.
   2. Construct a new object with said values.
   3. Push the object into the JSON object array.
   4. Add the new data to the page.
4. Stores the data in localStorage.
5. Checks localStorage on page load and writes data to page, if found.

**JS:**

```
// create data structure
var addressBook = {"entries": []}  // this should be JSON array object

// create data object to contain form data
function AddressBookEntry(name, address, email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.email = email;
}

// create onclick function for button
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
    // get values from each form field
    var name = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var address = document.getElementById("useraddress").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("useremail").value;

    // create new object using consturctor
    var newAddress = new AddressBookEntry(name, address, email);
    var jAddress = JSON.stringify(newAddress);

    // push new object into array
    addressBook.push(jAddress);
    localStorage.setItem("addressBook", JSON.stringify(addressBook));

    // add information to page

    // write data to the page

    // store the data

    // read from storage and write to page if data found
```

I'm able to create the JSON object, get the data from the form and throw it into the constructor to create a new object, and then turn that into a JSON object, but I can't get this object to pass to the array, and everything breaks down at this point.

What am I missing?

Comment: what do you mean by "I can't get this object to pass to the array"?

Comment: the correct is addressBook.entries.push(jAddress). AddressBook is of type object not array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to do instead is 
`addressBook.entries.push(jAddress)`.

**AddressBook** is of type object not array

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to push() into addressBook, which you have defined as an object with an array (entries) inside it. Try:

```
addressBook.entries.push( newAddress );
```

and note that you don't need to stringify newAddress in order to add it to the array or localStorage. Using JSON.stringify() on addressBook is enough.

I have wrapped your onclick handler into a function that fires when the page loads to ensure that the form submit object exists before it tries to add the event handler. You can run the page in your browser script debugger to test the output into the array.

Here is a full test:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">



// create data object to contain form data
function AddressBookEntry(name, address, email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.email = email;
}

function go(){
    // create data structure
    var addressBook = {entries:[]};  // this should be JSON array object

    // create onclick function for button
    document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
        // get values from each form field
        var name = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var address = document.getElementById("useraddress").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("useremail").value;

        // create new object using consturctor
        var newAddress = new AddressBookEntry(name, address, email);
        //var jAddress = JSON.stringify(newAddress);

        // push new object into array
        addressBook.entries.push(newAddress);
        localStorage.setItem("addressBook", JSON.stringify(addressBook));

        // add information to page

        // write data to the page
        console.log(addressBook);
        // store the data

        // read from storage and write to page if data found

        return true;
    }

    } 
</script>
</head>

<body onload="go()">

    <form>
    <fieldset>
        <label id="namefield">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstlast" id="username">
        </br>
        <label id="address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="useraddress">
        </br>
        <label id="emailfield">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="useremail">
        </br>
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Save</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```